# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ngFor not displaying anything in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation" *ngFor="let nav of navList">
      {{ nav }} 
</div>
```

TS:

```
@Input() navList: string[] = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
```

Ok, so these are my files, the parts where i create the variable and initialize it in the TS with the mock values, and when i call it in the HTML using the ngFor property. Nothing is displayed in the web page and this is the error it returns:

NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

And yes, I have the Common Module and the Browser module and the browser animation module all imported in the app.module and in the component's module. Does anyone know what else should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen, if you are not declaring  in declarations of app.module.ts.

Comment: The error was similar to this, i was declaring it in the component's module, but i forgot to import the module (where the component was declared) in app.module. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what problem you are having but I tried to make simple ngFor in this project and work fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-beeizd?file=src/app/app.component.html